# Angular no devuelve una excepción como error

Tags: angular

El método que hace la petición:

```
public update(reserva: Reserva): Observable<Reserva>{
  let data = {
   service: 'updateReserva',
   reserva: reserva
  }
  return this.http.put<Reserva>(this.URL, JSON.stringify(data))

}


update(){

   this.http.update(this.reservaModel).subscribe({

     next: (reserva: Reserva)=>{
       console.log(reserva)
     },
     error: (error: Error)=>{
      
       console.log(error)
     },
     complete:()=>{
      this.editando = false;
      this.current_edit = -1;
     }
     })
 }
```

La salida es un mensaje de excepción, pues hay una violación de constraints pero es tratado en el objeto next: en lugar de en el objeto error:

"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dwes_manana_laravel_tfg`.`reservas`, CONSTRAINT `reservas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pista_id`, `tramo_id`) REFERENCES `pista_tramo` (`pista_id`, `tramo_id`))",
"23000"

Porqué lo trata en next:???

Comment: ¿Qué hace la función `handleError`?

Comment: Perdón, olvidé eliminarla. Está ahí porque traté de manejarlo de alguna forma, pero ni siquiera llega ahí pues no viene como error. Quiero decir que llega un error, pero es tratado en next, con lo que no puedo tratarlo como error

Comment: Que código de status estas devolviendo en la respuesta? Porque si devuelves `2xx` el http de angular la procesa como válida.